# How to fix image saving that's cutting off y-axis text in R?

Tags: r, image, heatmap

I have a heatmap where the text for the y-axis keeps getting cut off. The text gets cut off whether I try to save the image manually in RStudio export, or using:

```
png(filename)
Heatmap(pathways, name = "log p-value", column_title = "Genesets", 
        cluster_rows = FALSE,  row_names_side = "left", col = col_fun)
dev.off()
```

It also does not matter how I change the figure width and height - changing these parameters changes the size of the heatmap squares but the text cut off is always the same amount.

Example image:
[image]

I've cropped off the X axis because I can't share it, it is only the Y axis that I am having the problem with as shown. Also for reference I make the heatmap using the `complexheatmap` package.

Edit: trying this also doesn't seem to do anything:

```
par(mar=c(100,100,100,100)+10)
png(filename='test.png', width=700, height=700)
Heatmap(df_pathways, name = "log p-value", column_title = "Genesets", 
        cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE,  row_names_side = "left", col = col_fun)
graphics.off()
```

Example input data:

```
pathways <-
structure(list(Group1 = c(9.420318259, 4.836092781, 5.561049165, 
8.190548144, 6.71227316, 4.095942487, 4.992794151, 5.552164863, 
4.34153332, 5.895592291, 7.553546365, 4.992782053, 6.053009309, 
6.860701322, 5.801092847, 5.148352899, 4.890727291, 4.228175167, 
5.804415571, 4.589825753), Group2 = c(14.57805564, 10.81418654, 
11.09736375, 10.32521712, 12.0145571, 10.07735354, 10.02001419, 
9.218294382, 10.09808164, 8.177240205, 8.657878442, 9.835699421, 
8.687931231, 8.31684452, 8.798453748, 7.760651767, 7.982599836, 
8.300396581, 8.249833908, 7.951599435), Group3 = c(14.49131554, 
13.3205827, 12.12174012, 10.44766272, 11.01869555, 11.09934699, 
11.24184793, 10.09879495, 9.876597118, 9.654484641, 10.91601179, 
9.873567424, 8.476802302, 8.318460384, 7.975284646, 7.409538041, 
8.258878348, 6.821340952, 7.075861702, 7.922657108), Group4 = c(11.44447147, 
10.69676399, 9.595976655, 8.394853352, 8.82546953, 7.762112046, 
7.146613208, 7.773426526, 7.445916643, 6.928897709, 6.969416034, 
7.90504739, 5.971561206, 6.126050462, 6.208332721, 6.93495916, 
6.529806574, 5.727539932, 7.097356964, 4.882623805), Group5 = c(22.86835197, 
12.70083108, 10.05632122, 8.487520597, 4.207896212, 10.08721586, 
9.726807084, 9.539543451, 12.26094928, 12.23048716, 7.885614665, 
6.993219914, 11.35470645, 11.22311857, 10.94297858, 9.214002287, 
7.197041788, 10.59080554, 5.08232173, 9.237584441), Group6 = c(10.62687539, 
12.39464562, 8.714396722, 7.436886904, 9.303280092, 8.266037496, 
8.650863908, 7.753285867, 6.151852334, 7.227066955, 5.589700078, 
7.271066145, 7.172215654, 6.000920914, 6.458410247, 5.790443124, 
7.461916094, 7.272885252, 5.318945244, 6.308454021), Group7 = c(11.09404106, 
11.13903127, 9.363613884, 8.811864251, 9.255305005, 8.082707248, 
7.101057322, 8.064874227, 7.29823506, 7.154725479, 7.256169907, 
7.56145848, 6.155332798, 6.349384361, 6.420303272, 7.232379137, 
6.821000583, 5.934088344, 7.368454621, 5.0727153)), row.names = c("Cardiac Hypertrophy Signaling (Enhanced)", 
"Estrogen Receptor Signaling", "Role of NFAT in Cardiac Hypertrophy", 
"Protein Kinase A Signaling", "Molecular Mechanisms of Cancer", 
"Opioid Signaling Pathway", "Hepatic Fibrosis Signaling Pathway", 
"Gap Junction Signaling", "G-Protein Coupled Receptor Signaling", 
"White Adipose Tissue Browning Pathway", "Sperm Motility", "Factors Promoting Cardiogenesis in Vertebrates", 
"Nitric Oxide Signaling in the Cardiovascular System", "Relaxin Signaling", 
"Cellular Effects of Sildenafil (Viagra)", "Insulin Secretion Signaling Pathway", 
"Colorectal Cancer Metastasis Signaling", "Ovarian Cancer Signaling", 
"PPARÎ±/RXRÎ± Activation", "Corticotropin Releasing Hormone Signaling"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe changing `mar` in `par` can help. E.g. `par(mar = c(5, 8, 4, 2) + 0.1)`

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it doesn't seem to have worked for me no matter what numbers I set it to

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? It will attract more replies methinks (or else it's each person replying that has to make one => it's more efficient if the op does it).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion - added in some data that should work with the ```Heatmap()``` function I use here

Comment: Increasing the  `Heatmap` parameter `row_names_max_width` from the default `unit(6, "cm")` to something like `row_names_max_width = unit(12, "cm")` should allow you to accommodate longer row names, if that is the issue you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment above: I think you are talking about the truncated row labels when you say "text for the y-axis". If that is indeed the issue you are struggling with, then increasing the `Heatmap` parameter `row_names_max_width` from the default `unit(6, "cm")` to something like `row_names_max_width = unit(12, "cm")` should allow you to accommodate longer row labels.

```r
library(ComplexHeatmap)

## using your provided data as df_pathways

Heatmap(df_pathways, name = "log p-value", column_title = "Genesets", 
        row_names_max_width = unit(12, "cm"),
        cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE,  row_names_side = "left")
#> Warning: The input is a data frame, convert it to the matrix.
```

[image]